# Is it ethical to use someone else's research as an illustrative case?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, copyright

I have developed a framework for describing a phenomenon in organizations and would like to illustrate its use by referring to a case study published by another author. In other words, I would be fitting another study's descriptions to my own framework.

The paper will be published in conference proceedings.

So, is it fair game to use another person's study to illustrate my framework?

I have my own field work that I would like to use alongside the other study, so the other author's case study is complementary and... illustrative.

Comment: I see this as perfectly adequate. I've done it myself.

Comment: Of course this is fine, with proper attribution to the other study, etc. This is what scholarship is about.

Comment: Even if not technically required to do so, you might be benefited by contacting the original authors and asking their permission or proposing a collaboration.

Comment: @BryanKrause Good point! It could present an opportunity to build a relationship with the original authors. 

Thanks all for the feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire point of publication is to get your work out there for other people to use as a basis for further work. (The whole "standing on the shoulders of giants" thing.)

If a researcher is going to be upset about someone else taking their work and using it as a basis of further work, then they shouldn't be publishing it in the first place. (*E.g.* many companies keep research results "trade secret", which they use internally and never publish.)

In the fields I'm familiar with, it's perfectly acceptable to take published results and re-analyze them or use them as a basis for further work.

That said, there are some caveats. Among these (but not a comprehensive list): Be sure to give appropriate citations and credit as to the origin of the work at every reasonable opportunity - avoid implying that this is your data, even by omission. Be careful about copyright - verbatim copying of text and figures without explicit permission is usually proscribed, but using the underlying data (facts, numbers, general ideas) is normally not. Be sure to conform to the particular norms in your field, if any, about re-use of datasets - in some fields there's norms about data re-use, as data collection may be laborious and researchers who spend a lot of effort making datasets don't want to be "scooped" on follow-up work by people who swoop in  with a quick re-analysis.

But generally speaking, if the data are available from a published source, you're not breaking copyright, and you're not doing anything that's going to prevent the original authors from publishing additional work, you should be able to use the published data in your paper. (With appropriate citation, of course.)

Comment: A suggestion for attribution, illustrated with tables: Put an obvious citation very close to the start of your own article. Something along the lines of "The data in Table 2, Table 3, and Table 4 is taken from <cite>." Then on each and every table you have copied, put a very obvious note saying "Data taken from <cite>." That is, it should be very hard to ignore that you are saying where the data comes from.

Answer (score -4):

It is unethical as well as illegal in the following circumstances:

- The contents (texts, figures, results) are copied verbatim from the other source.
- Even though the texts are written after self interpretation, citation is missing.
- If the figures are being used, the permission has not been taken. One should be extremely careful with this, as sometimes, authors are unaware of their own copyright after publication. In such a case, taking permission from only the authors would not suffice. The publisher must be asked for the same.

However, to answer your question, the case study may be presented indirectly by properly citing the original source. For e.g.

> ... We demonstrate the method of how to use case study which closely follows the case study presented in [reference]. ...

Comment: If it's inappropriate to refer and/or use other scholars'/researchers' work, even with appropriate citation and attribution, how can anything get done? in the U.S., although IANAL, this would surely fall under "fair use". In fact, I'd think that this was exactly the primary goal of "fair use".